# Pytest fixture not able to quit the test after execution in python pytest

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I am using below fixture in conftest.py for open and close browser :
conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def browser():
    print("Setting up webdriver connection...")
    global driver
    if driver is None:
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type",1)
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
        driver.maximize_window()
        yield driver
        driver.quit()
        print("Webdriver connection closed..")
```

In my Test Class I have below step test_login :

```
def test_login(self, browser):
        login_page = pagep.LoginPage(browser)
        login_page.login('hptest376@gmail.com', "test12345*")
        login_page.login('user', "pwd")
        assert "Sum" in browser.title
```

And after test_login I have one more test step in my Test Class:

```
def test_ppt(a):
    a=12
    print a
```

Issue : I am getting error in fixture  at driver.quit() and browser is not closing.

If I remove the "test_ppt(a)" step after "test_login(self, browser)" then the test runs fine.

Want to know what i need to update in my fixture "browser()" so that driver.quit() is executed.

Comment: What error you are getting at `driver.quit()`?

Comment: I have figured out that the test was falling in next step i.e. test_ppt(a) where it was trying to close the browser as the scope of fixture was 'session' . I changed the scope of fixture to 'function' and the test is passing now.                                      
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def browser():

Answer (score 0):

Changed the scope of fixture to 'function' and the test is passing now.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function') 
def browser():
```